# Getting error in scss file when installing vuetify.js

Tags: sass, vuetify.js, webpack-4

I have installed vuetify.js but it's giving me error in webpack configuration.

I have changed my webpack v4 configuration, also installed 
node-sass and sass-loader

Webpack.config.js

```
{
    test:  /\.(s*)css$/,
    loader:['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
}
```

This is the error

ERROR in ./node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/main.sass 3:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (3:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| // Modeled after ITCSS https://www.xfive.co/blog/itcss-scalable-maintainable-css-architecture/
|

> @import './settings/_index'
>   | @import './tools/_index'
>   | @import './generic/_index'
>    @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/framework.js 5:0-33
>    @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/index.js
>    @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/header/Header.vue
>    @ ./src/header/Header.vue
>    @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/app/App.vue
>    @ ./src/app/App.vue
>    @ ./src/index.js

Comment: how did you setup your project? Did you use the default vue webpack setup?

Comment: @SimonThiel No I haven't used the default vue webpack setup, although I externally made configurations in webpack, these configs works fine for css but not for scss

Comment: Does it work if you install the below dependencies?

Comment: @SimonThiel No, I installed them but that didn't work for me

Answer (score 3):

I use the following installed the following dependencies and it works fine for me:

```
    "sass": "^1.22.9",
    "sass-loader": "^7.2.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^0.5.0",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

did you add this `lang="scss"` to your  tag ?
when you use scss you should have this format of style tag

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>...</style>
```